Asymptotics of $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tan^{-1}(x^n)}{\sqrt{1 - x^n}} \, dx $
Working around this question, I tried to compute
$$I_n=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tan^{-1}(x^n)}{\sqrt{1 - x^n}} \, dx $$ which I have been unable to express using Mathematica for general $n$.
Some tedious work led me to
$$I_n=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{n}\,\,\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3 n+2}{2 n}\right)}\,\,\,\, _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{n+1}{2 n},\frac{2 n+1}{2 n};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3 n+2}{4 n},\frac{5 n+2}{4 n};-1\right)$$
If $n$ is a real positive number (not necessarily an integer) or a complex, it works fine.
Where the problem comes is when I try to build the asymptotics : the front factor does not make any problem using Stirling approximation but I am stuck with the hypergeometric function.
At the time, thanks to  @Mariusz Iwaniuk, the only thing I know is that
$$L=\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{limit}}\, _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{n+1}{2 n},\frac{2 n+1}{2 n};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3 n+2}{4 n},\frac{5 n+2}{4 n};-1\right)$$ $$L=\sec ^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{2}\right) \,\cosh^{-1}\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)$$
Numerically, for infinitely large values of $n$, making the coefficients rational,
$$\, _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{n+1}{2 n},\frac{2 n+1}{2 n};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3 n+2}{4 n},\frac{5 n+2}{4 n};-1\right) \sim L \left(1-\frac{57}{971 n}+\frac{26}{775 n^2}-\frac{34}{1741
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$
This makes that, for the time being, using rationalized coefficients
$$I_n=\frac{4257}{2435 n}-\frac{817}{695 n^2}+\frac{1287}{1201
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
My question is :
Can we obtain the exact first coefficients of the asymptotics of the hypergeometric function ?

Performing the change of integration variables from $x$ to $t$ via $x=t^{1/n}$ yields
$$
I_n  = \frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 {t^{1/n} \frac{{\arctan (t)}}{t}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 - t} }}{\rm d}t} .
$$
We can expand $t^{1/n}=\exp((1/n)\log t)$ via the Maclaurin series of the exponential function, which gives
$$
I_n  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{a_k }}{{n^k }}} 
$$
with
\begin{align*}
a_k &=\frac{1}{{(k - 1)!}}\int_0^1 {\frac{{\arctan (t)}}{t}\frac{{\log ^{k - 1} t}}{{\sqrt {1 - t} }}{\rm d}t} 
\\[2ex] &=\frac{{( - 1)^{k - 1} }}{{(k - 1)!}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\arctan ({\rm e}^{ - t} )}}{{\sqrt {1 - {\rm e}^{ - t} } }}t^{k - 1} {\rm d}t},
\end{align*}
for $k\ge 1$. I am unsure whether these integrals can be evaluated in terms of known constants or not.
